# creating report in an unplanned mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I created a website for poll, users are meant to register and vote. I created only one table for user's information and commment. below is the columns and rows for the table:

Users:

columns:   username password agree_1 reason_1 agree_2 reason_2

rows:      paul     testing   yes     NULL     no      because i don't like it

i decided to make this table this way because the questions are in a (tables) and are over 100 lines each. and again, from the form, if you agree, you will state no reason(that's the reason for the null), but if you disagree, you will have to state your reasons. my question is:

how do i prepare a standard report for such an unplanned database?
how do i count the number of people who agreed by saying yes and the number of people who said no?
for those who said no, how do i extract their reason?

i want this report to be extracted and displayed using php. Am using mysql and php.

Comment: So agree_1 and agree_2 are answers to different questions?

Comment: Yes you guessed that right. They are answers to different questions.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, I think you'd be best restructuring your table with [normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) in mind:

```
users
- id
- email
- name

polls
- id
- name

questions
- id
- poll_id
- question
- order

answers
- id
- question_id
- user_id
- answer
```

Then, hopefully, your requirements and the queries you need will become clearer. For example, to query the number of people who gave each unique answered to question #34:

```
SELECT
    answer,
    count(*) AS 'people'
FROM answers
WHERE question_id = 34
GROUP BY answer
```

Will return something like:

```
answer    people
yes       15
no        17
null      3
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please the relation is quite confusing. Can you show me the columns that are primary key, and ones that are secondary key. Please make it more clear.thanks

Comment: Anything called id is a PK, anything _id links to a PK